# Determine if TURN is used from webrtc getStats api data

Tags: android, webrtc, webrtc-android

I am using WebRTC getStats() API on android to get stats and I am getting most of the data which I need. But I can't find data to determine if TURN used or not.

Please check the sample json data. https://pastebin.com/v89aaL2H

```
private void getStats() {
if (peerConnection == null || isError) {
    return;
}
boolean success = peerConnection.getStats(reports -> events.onPeerConnectionStatsReady(reports), null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using legacy stats. So, let me answer your question based on  legacy stats -

In your legacy stats, `googCandidatePair` list represent the ICE candidate pairs ( a pairing of a local and a remote ICE candidate ) for your current WebRTC session. If you look into the `googCandidatePair` list you will find the candidate pairs that is currently being used by a transport (`googCandidatePair.googActiveConnection` will be true in that case ).

Now you can look into the local and remote candidate type ( `googLocalCandidateType`, and `googRemoteCandidateType` ) of this active `googCandidatePair` to know what exactly you are using for your transport.

For example, from the sample stats dump - you are using stun only.

*Note: You might also be interested in reading  [Chrome Standard getStats() Migration Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1z-D4SngG36WPiMuRvWeTMN7mWQXrf1XKZwVl3Nf1BIE)*